# Macbook Pro Apple logo brightness reacts to sound?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio

I was watching a movie on netflix with the back of the laptop facing the wall. It was pretty dark in the room I was in and I noticed that whenever there was nobody talking/less sound the illuminated Apple logo would dim down. Whenever someone started speaking it would light up again. I thought it couldve been the backlight of the white subtitles but in a scene when theres just two people talking I can clearly see the apple logo's brightness lower whenever it goes silent. Its not really a problem for me, I was just wondering if anybody else had noticed it and if it's normal in the first place.

Thanks in advance,

John